# Viewstate exceptions

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

I get the following exceptions every couple of days:

```
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster. ---> System.Web.UI.ViewStateException: Invalid viewstate.
```

The thing is that I have a machine key set, and I also use only a single server (ie no cluster). So why is this exception happening? The only thing I can think of is that I keep reseting the IIS server, but I can't quite work out why that's a problem. Do you guys see this exception on a regular basis?

For reference, the following exists under my 'system.web':

```
<machineKey validationKey="Blah1" decryptionKey="Blah2" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
```

Comment: Lots of information if you want to dig for it:  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Validation+of+viewstate+MAC+failed  (I'm not sure what the real answer is. :/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validation of Viewstate MAC failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908084/validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed)

Comment: Is there any specific page you see this most frequently on?

Comment: Is the page HTML pretty large?  We've experienced this with large pages.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate a little on Brian's point, the reason pages which are 'pretty large' experience problems is that those pages are sometimes rendered so slowly that you press the 'submit' button before the ViewState has finished downloading, which causes it to appear corrupted and generates the error.

The only solutions to this are:

1. disable viewstate completely
2. use a script to only enable submit after the page is fully loaded
3. make sure ViewState is as near the top of the page as possible (which I think is bad for SEO if your site is public).

You could try and prove this were the case by seeing if there were any correlation between the speed pages were being loaded and the timing of the exception.  Using a tool like LogParser could help with this.